# Send nested containers on dbus via ssh without gdbus

Tags: python, dbus, dbus-python

I need to send a message to a method with signature `(bbb)`. Monitoring the system calls, I see that the datatype sent to this method is `variant:struct`.

I am able to send simple, not nested, data types with

```
DBUS_SEND = ["dbus-send", "--system", "--dest=com.destination",
            "--type=method_call",   "--print-reply", "/com/destination",
             "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set", "string:\"com.destination\"",
             "string:\"color\"",  "variant:string:\"black\""]

dbus_send_command = ' '.join(n for n in DBUS_SEND)
subprocess.call(['ssh', '-tt', 'user@machine', dbus_send_command])
```

The problem is that`dbus-send` does not support neither nested containers, nor `struct`, and `gdbus` is not available on the remote.

Would it be possible to use `pydbus` or any other alternatives to send messages with nested containers to a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `busctl` installed on the machine, so we can send this type of message